# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Amazon.trim') In react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. And I have created a form. But now its not sending data to server. when I click on Submit button. its keep throwing error like this

```
 undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Amazon.trim')
```

so whats wrong with my code please help.
here is my code

```
export default function Add(props) {


  const { navigation } = props

  const data = props.route.params.data

   const amazonD =  data.service_details_data[0] ? data.service_details_data[0].amazon_name : ''

  const [AmazonError, setAmazonError] = useState([]);
  const [Amazon, setAmazon] = useState(undefined);

  const validateInputs = () => {

    if (!Amazon.trim()) {
      setAmazonError('Please Fill The Input')
      return;
    }
    else 
    {

        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=submitting form data to api start+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
{
  
    const data = props.route.params.data
    const phpid = data.service_details_data[0] ? data.service_details_data[0].id : ''


    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by",'leadTagNumber']).then(response => {


  fetch('https://xyztech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata/merchant_service_details', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
      body: JSON.stringify([{ some data}])
    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      Alert.alert("File uploaded");
      return response.json();
    });
  });
  // event.preventDefault();
  }
  //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++submitting form data to api end++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

      Alert.alert("success")
      return;
    }
  };

    const handleAmazon = (text) => {
    setAmazonError('')
    setAmazon(text)
    }
  

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <ScrollView style={{flex: 1,}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>        

          <TextInput 
                        maxLength={30}
                        placeholder="Amazon *"
                        style={styles.inputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(text)=>handleAmazon(text)}
                        // value={Amazon}
                        defaultValue={amazonD}
                        value = {Amazon} />
                           <Text style={{color :'red'}}>{AmazonError}</Text>
     
         </ScrollView>
        <Button
          style={styles.inputStyleB}
          title="Submit"
          color="#FF8C00"
          onPress={() => validateInputs()}
        />
        </View>
  )
}
```

please ignore this = I am new to react native. And I have created a form. But now its not sending data to server. when I click on Submit button. its keep throwing error like this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set Amazon to undefined in useState and then try to access it.

Comment: yes I am createing two values one is only value and second is default value when I submit form and then reload app and open this form then I see values which I have submitted previously But now if I again click on that button its throwing error like this but when I change all values then only form will submit But I want that if user change only one value then also form have to be submitted

Comment: Or what should I use instead of Undefined

Comment: @SohilShaikh It must be string I think , as you are applying trim on it.

Comment: no I have try this when I put empty string instead of undefined then. my previous form filled data not showing. I want to dispay user previous form filled data. so next time user just edit one record and submit

Comment: You can use empty string and instead of checking trim, you can use if (!Amazon.length) so if user has entered text in input field it must be having some length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229611/discussion-between-rohit-and-sohil-shaikh).

Answer (score 0):

I have also declared such type of error but I will solve it by in the use state I have kept it empty not giving any value for use state then I will use an empty string then it solves.....